# Moving a directory containing a subproject / remains from project within project

Tags: git

Due to unnecessary long names for some of my directories I went ahead to rename them. This worked fine for two of them but not for a third due to...

```
  git mv DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/ programmeringMedCSharpOchXNA
fatal: source directory is empty, source=DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar, destination=programmeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar
```

It is very true that this directory is empty (no .git directory either), however, i'm not sure why it matters..

I might have once added a subprject here, but i'm not 100% sure, it might have just been another repository inside another (not as a subproject). I'm fairly new to git so it's very possible i did something strangely.

This is what i've done in order to find out more... it hasn't led me to a solution

```
  git submodule status
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar'

  cat .gitmodules
cat: .gitmodules: No such file or directory

  grep -r UniWar .git/**
Binary file .git/index matches
```

Opening .git/index in vim, it looks like a normal text file and there is no 'UniWar' found anywhere inside of it. Opening it in notepad shows a match amongst the bogus characters.

Simply trying to git remove the directory won't work either...

```
  git rm -r DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar
rm 'DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar'
Unlink of file 'DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)? y
Unlink of file 'DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)? n
fatal: git rm: 'DA305A-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt/UniWar': Permission denied
```

No clue why i get permission denied, i couldn't find any file handles matching 'UniWar'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My issue was resolved by first doing a normal

`rm -r DA305-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt`

### followed by

`git rm -r DA305-ProgrammeringMedCSharpOchXNA/Projekt`

(this time without permission denied error). I was then allowed to move the directory.